# UIButton with style of keyboard buttons

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I am creating a custom keyboard for only numerical input.  I would prefer the keyboard look as much like the iOS keyboard as possible, but I am not too sure if the default keyboard button graphics are something we can use or if apple has them locked up.

ARE buttons able to have such a style without having to use images I build myself?  Or is the only way to mirror that design by building images that look similar?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad` or `UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad` keyboard types for a text field or text view?

Comment: I need only numeric digits to be input.  And on the ipad the 'numeric' keypad also has symbols and characters.

Comment: That isn't a problem. Since you have to deal with users making use of Bluetooth keyboards, you need to deal with non-numeric input anyway.

Comment: How is it not a problem?  If the numeric pad shows with other keys as options, that defeats what I want to do.  Only have numbers on the keyboard.  Is there a way to possibly grey out keys I dont want to use?

Comment: My point is, even if you add a numbers-only keyboard on the iPad, a user may still use a Bluetooth keyboard. This will allow them to type in any characters they want. Therefore, you must properly validate a user's input for non-numeric key presses or to prevent the user from pasting text into the text field. Given all of this, there's no reason not to use the standard "numeric" keyboard on the iPad even though it has other keys on it. And no, there is no way to grey out or disable keys on the standard keyboard.

Comment: That is an interesting point rmaddy, and I will have to talk to a superior about wether or not the users this app is for will use a bluetooth keyboard.

Comment: Talking to a superior wont help. It is the user's decision, not your boss's. No app has control over whether someone can use a Bluetooth keyboard or not.

Answer (score 1):

You're able to define customized keyboards similar to Apple's.  Take a look at the project here: https://github.com/kulpreetchilana/Custom-iOS-Keyboards

It contains graphics that emulate the look and feel of the iOS keyboard.  It's Cocoapods project as well.

Comment: I can't really be using any outsourced materials.  And it still seems as if they are using custom images.  To answer my question, is that the only way to get the same button design?

Comment: You can use the UIKit-Artwork-Extractor (https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor) and see if the button graphics are there.